# Git: merge branch excluding last commit

Tags: git, git-merge

The common case is to merge a branch up to its last commit:

```
      A---B---C topic
     /         \
D---E---F---G---H master
```

But I wanted to exclude the last commit, like this:

```
        A---B---C topic
       /     \
  D---E---F---G  master
```

Is it possible to merge the `topic` branch into master without including `topic`'s last commit?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge Also, why do you have two commits with the same name?

Comment: Impossible to tell what you're asking. Do you mean you want to merge `C` into `master` without moving the branch pointer `topic`? What does `D` have to do with anything? You might have better luck if you show us before/after diagrams of what you're trying to do. Also, it's "please", not "pls".

Comment: i mean "merge B into master without C".

Comment: Wait, your "after" diagram has suddenly lost commit "H". What happened to it? Was that intentional?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When merging, you don't need to say a branch name, you just need a commit reference.

Assuming `B` is the penultimate commit on the branch `topic`, you could do:

```
git checkout master
git merge topic~
```

Where the `~` means "the commit before". You can learn more about how to reference commits with `man gitrevisions`.

As an alternative, you could provide the SHA1 of the commit `B` directly.

Comment: git merge topic~${n} can do it. 但是如何根据SHA1来指定合并到指定的提交。

Comment: Is this answer still correct in 2021? Or do we use `cherry-pick` instead?

Comment: @Echoes `cherry-pick <branch-name>` does the opposite of what was discussed in this case (only gets the last commit). If you mean `cherry-pick <penultimate-commit-sha1>` instead then it does a different thing - it only gets that commit, not the whole tree. Might be what you want, but the question had a different context

Answer (score 4):

> i mean "merge B into master without C". –  kangear 1 min ago

Then just do exactly that. Merge `B` into `master`. It's completely valid to merge by commit ID rather than by branch name:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge B
```